Как передать кортеж с Postman в asp.net web api
Делаю систему заказов. Есть таккой вот тип:
public sealed record SmthRequest
{
    public Guid WorkshopId { get; set; }
    public Guid SupplyId { get; set; }
    public List<(Guid id, int count)> MaterialIds { get; set; } = new List<(Guid, int)>();
}

Как правильно передать MaterialIds используя Postman или Swagger?
UPD: сделал эндпоинт:
[HttpGet("get-tuple")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTuple() =>
    Ok(new SmthRequest(
        Guid.NewGuid(),
        Guid.NewGuid(),
        new List<(Guid id, int count)>()
        {
            (Guid.NewGuid(), 1),
            (Guid.NewGuid(), 2),
            (Guid.NewGuid(), 3),
            (Guid.NewGuid(), 4),
            (Guid.NewGuid(), 5),
        }
    ));

При запросе получаю ответ:
{
    "x1": "4d97ab93-bdca-421d-8549-122d5e1d42b9",
    "x2": "c0a956d1-908a-495b-add6-2aca2941286a",
    "x3": [
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {}
    ]
}

Пробовал передавать такой вариант:
{
    "WorkshopId": "5da98ac2-b589-4261-ad8c-8a0d21111dca",
    "MaterialIds": [
        {
            "Item1": "41edd8f3-15c5-4259-bfab-c35b21a00d2f",
            "Item2": 5
        },
        {
            "Item1": "48c313c0-032a-4d59-9120-a17e98ab6ba9",
            "Item2": 10
        }
    ]
}

И такой:
{
    "WorkshopId": "5da98ac2-b589-4261-ad8c-8a0d21111dca",
    "MaterialIds": [
        {
            "id": "41edd8f3-15c5-4259-bfab-c35b21a00d2f",
            "count": 5
        },
        {
            "id": "48c313c0-032a-4d59-9120-a17e98ab6ba9",
            "count": 10
        }
    ]
}

И ни один из них не передаёт значение кортежа на сервер.

Забыли поставить очень важную метку - язык, теряете так просмотры... Касательно вопроса: Кортежи не являются свойствами, это набор полей, не более. Ну а сериализатор в свою очередь, по умолчанию сериализирует только свойства, вот у вас и пустота. Хотите видеть там и данные кортежей, включайте IncludeFields в настройках сериализатора. На вопрос "что передавать": что-то вроде этого: { "WorkshopId": "...", "MaterialIds": [ { "Item1": "...", "Item2": 1 }, ... ] }. А так, вы не по назначению используете кортежи, не ленитесь, сделайте класс...

@EvgeniyZ, спасибо, изменил тег. За класс понимаю, просто думал, что можно как-то это передать в таком формате. Оказывается, что нет (Либо я так понимаю)

Передавать в таком формате вы можете, но по умолчанию у кортежей названия переменных, это ItemЧисло, ибо такое поле создается "под капотом". Если такое не смущает, считаете данное поведение удобным, то вон, JSON запроса выше, ну а если такое не нравиться, то можете изобрести свои костыли, только вот стоит оно того? Я думаю, нет...  Так что, лучше сделать класс, который будет строго описывать конкретный объект.

@EvgeniyZ, спасибо, я дополнил ответ. Я уже пробовал эти варианты и они не работают

Значит вы делаете что-то не то, например, забыли про IncludeFields... Вот ваш JSON и ваш класс, которые успешно десериализируются (внимание на настройку).

Зависит от используемого (де)сериализатора. Ведь можно передавать данные в JSON, XML, CSV и других текстовых форматах. А также в бинарных форматах: ProtoBuf, MessagePack и др. По умолчанию используется System.Text.Json. Мысль посмотреть, что возвращает эндпойнт - правильная. И правильно указал EvgeniyZ, что нужно как минимум указать IncludeFields, а лучше не использовать кортежи.

Configure System.Text.Json-based formatters - так можно задать настройки сериализатора в ASP.NET проекте.

Как-то так, используйте опцию сериализатора IncludeFields.
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<(Guid, int)> list = [             
        (Guid.NewGuid(), 1),
        (Guid.NewGuid(), 2),
        (Guid.NewGuid(), 3),
        (Guid.NewGuid(), 4),
        (Guid.NewGuid(), 5), 
    ];
    JsonSerializerOptions options = new() { IncludeFields = true, WriteIndented = true };
    string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(list, options);
    Console.WriteLine(json);

    var items = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<(Guid, int)>>(json, options);
    foreach ((Guid guid, int number) in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{guid}, {number}");
    }
}

Вывод в консоль
[
  {
    "Item1": "5ff7a2d3-98ea-4b9f-9df5-3fdb94a7807f",
    "Item2": 1
  },
  {
    "Item1": "5526be3c-a0ff-42dd-bbb3-844c97804f80",
    "Item2": 2
  },
  {
    "Item1": "da82a099-28c0-43ee-a61e-972737d5c816",
    "Item2": 3
  },
  {
    "Item1": "1ee23906-3c11-4992-a7ef-2387421a9e19",
    "Item2": 4
  },
  {
    "Item1": "ba06dd98-6da8-49e5-90d7-8bc02d740ff5",
    "Item2": 5
  }
]
5ff7a2d3-98ea-4b9f-9df5-3fdb94a7807f, 1
5526be3c-a0ff-42dd-bbb3-844c97804f80, 2
da82a099-28c0-43ee-a61e-972737d5c816, 3
1ee23906-3c11-4992-a7ef-2387421a9e19, 4
ba06dd98-6da8-49e5-90d7-8bc02d740ff5, 5

То есть в вашем случае решение выглядит так:
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;
});  

